# Elasticsearch analyze API shows wrong tokens with 1.X version when used according to 7.X syntax

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-analyzers, elasticsearch-1.7.5

While working on one of the user's queries, where initially I assumed he was using the latest version and when he showed [analyze API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/indices-analyze.html#indices-analyze), it was surprising.

**Custom analyzer for which tokens needs to be checked**

```
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "filter": {
                "splcharfilter": {
                    "type": "pattern_capture",
                    "preserve_original": true,
                    "patterns": [
                        "([?/])"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "analyzer": {
                "splcharanalyzer": {
                    "tokenizer": "keyword",
                    "filter": [
                        "splcharfilter",
                        "lowercase"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Analyze API**

```
POST /_analyze

{
    "analyzer": "splcharanalyzer",
    "text" : "And/or"
}

Output

{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "analyzer", --> why this token
            "start_offset": 7,
            "end_offset": 15,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 1
        },
        {
            "token": "splcharanalyzer", --> why this token
            "start_offset": 19,
            "end_offset": 34,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 2
        },
        {
            "token": "text", --> why this token
            "start_offset": 42,
            "end_offset": 46,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 3
        },
        {
            "token": "and",
            "start_offset": 51,
            "end_offset": 54,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 4
        },
        {
            "token": "or",
            "start_offset": 58,
            "end_offset": 60,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 5
        }
    ]
}
```

**As its clearly shown above its generating so many tokens which are not correct**, when checked user mentioned he was using 1.7 version and followed the syntax provided in the latest version of elasticsearch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Elasticsearch 1.X version is quite old, and Elasticsearch by default opens the latest version of API and wondering the importance of analyze API for troubleshooting so many issues in Elasticsearch I am posting here the correct syntax of 1.X version, Hope this would help other old version users of Elasticsearch.

Elasticsearch 1.X analyze API documentation can be found [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/indices-analyze.html) and below are the correct tokens generated for text mentioned in the question.

```
  GET  /_analyze?analyzer=splcharanalyzer&text=And/or --> note its GET request
```

**Correct tokens generated for `And/or` with the analyzer posted in question for 1.X**

```
{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "and/or",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 6,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 1
        },
        {
            "token": "/",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 6,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 1
        }
    ]
}
```